# Image delete c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image on my computer that my program uses (loads it to a pictureBox).
at run time !'m trying to delete the picture from my computer,
but there is an error that says the image is open hens why it can not be
deleted.
I tried this code but it did not work

```
PICbefore.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName));
ProfilePic.Image = null;
File.Delete("C:\image.jgp");
```

Comment: May depend on the way you openned it

Comment: "I have an image on my computer that my program uses" is quite unspecific. Please provide some more code on how you display that image in your GUI. This will enable us to help you out :-)

Comment: have you tried disposing the ProfilePic.Image object?

Comment: @FabrizioMigotto Yep:(

Comment: I would try creating a stream, reading the stream into the PICbefore.Image, and then disposing of the stream.  I'm not sure why the code you posted isn't working, but I'm assuming the .FromFile is keeping it locked for some period of time.

Comment: @Aaron FromFile will keep a lock on image files.

Comment: @LarsTech thx, I wasn't aware, I always use streams - I've never had this issue.  Good to know though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this before.  From memory, the solution is to open a stream to read the file (using a `using` statement) and then load the bitmap via the stream and assign it.  That way you are in complete control of the life cycle of the file/stream and the `ProfilePic.Image` property never touches the file.

```
    var filename = @"c:\image.png";
    Image img;
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        img = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
    PICbefore.Image = img;
    File.Delete(filename);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the PictureBox's `Image` to null doesn't delete anything. It will cause the PictureBox to stop showing it but the image will still exist in memory until some arbitrary point in the future when Garbage Collection runs. You need to dispose of the image object.

```
PICbefore.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName));
Image img = ProfilePic.Image;
ProfilePic.Image = null;
img.Dispose();
File.Delete("C:\image.jgp");
```

I'm not sure what a PictureBox does if you dispose of the image it's currently holding so to be safe I remove it from the PictureBox before disposing. After it's disposed you should be able to delete the file.

Comment: Or better yet...a `using`.

Comment: No, as I commented on a deleted answer you can't use `using` when you load the image because it will dispose of it before it's actually drawn on the forms. `using` works great for DB connections that are opened, used, and disposed of rather quickly but not for this lifecycle of an image.

Comment: Since you're focused on this (rather crappy) example of an image, I'd point out that no form of the code you or the OP has posted is workable in real life.  So it's a moot point.  I'm simply saying that if you don't know about `Dispose`, you probably don't know about `using`, and you should.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and instead of being a Cargo Cult dev it helps to know the big picture and what's actually happening. `using` here will only make things worse.

Comment: Sticks and stones.  Curious, though...I was pointing out that that is exactly your problem:  you have no idea what the big picture is.  But whatever...

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to deal with what I think is the same issue you are having.  This is what worked for me (though actually this was WPF project - so maybe not exactly the same for you in your Winform app). I think the img.freeze() was a key part.

```
 if (File.Exists(filePathName))
            {
                // read the file this way to open as read-only and cache the image in memory for use rather than keeping it open/locked and preventing updates to it
                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePathName))
                {
                    img.BeginInit();
                    img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    img.StreamSource = fs;
                    img.EndInit();
                    img.Freeze();
                }

                gridChartBg.Background = new ImageBrush(img);
            }
```